# Node JS and Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend, crud

Basically what I want to do is Create a single record in my database and display it on my ejs template and also I want to be able to edit that ocassionally.
**PLEASE HELP**

Comment: there are a number of tutorials online I think you would be better served looking at those this site is not really designed to answer this broad a question.

Comment: check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohmYRtEHktI

Comment: Welcome to SO - check the guides before asking questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask